# Nuxt 3: plugin and global middleware infinite loop?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

Developing the app using Nuxt 3 I made a global middleware that should run before every page loads. The middleware should check the JWT token in cookies and ask the API about the user if JWT exists. It looks somehow like that.

```
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async (to, from) => {
    const {getUser, authByHash} = useAuthStore();
    await getUser();
})
```

The result - Nuxt DDOSes the API and sends requests every 1-2 seconds. Without any page refreshes and changes. What can it be?

P.S. Plugins execute repeatedly also

Comment: Global middleware is triggered before each route change. It will trigger every time you click any link to a different route, so it has no 1-2 seconds interval.

Comment: What is happening inside getUser method. Isn't there anoter navigation (like redirect after successful auth or a refresh maybe) that would trigger the middleware again? Might be useful to log `from.path` and `to.path` during each execution to track how the app is trying to flow.

Comment: I checked, to.path and from.path are the same. But a bit weird.

/_content/ws

And after that goes

No match found for location with path "/_content/ws"

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You have used probably plugin's own store function `useAuthStore()` for getting states and may be plugin repeated issues resulting page refresh and changes. Rather use Nuxt own composable like `useState()`

Secondly, you have to navigate somewhere after middleware run with combination of `navigateTo()` method but in your code after promise what will it do was not defined.

Thirdly, provide condition to the states like: `if(!authByHash) { await navigateTo('/') }` or something like this and redirect.

Fourthly, try to fetch states check point at the route validation level instead of middleware, something like the followings:

```
<script setup>
definePageMeta({
  validate: async (route) => {
    // Check if the id is made up of digits
    return /^\d+$/.test(route.params.id)
  }
})
</script>
```